# How do I import the samples from the developer.android website?

Tags: android, eclipse, sample

I usually click File>Import>Android>Import existing code into workspace>browse folders for the project>Finish

For these samples, it keeps giving me the message "Select at least one project". What's happening?

Comment: try file>import>android>existing projects ... and browse then add.. it nrmally works

Comment: Are you talking about `/adt-bundle/sdk/samples/android-version` samples ? Make sure you are on the outermost folder. DOn't go inside sub-folder for each project.

Comment: More generally, what are "the samples from the Android Developer Getting Started website" that you are referring to?

Comment: file>import>android>existing projects ? I don't think I have that.. take a look: http://i.imgur.com/oYihdAh.jpg  . If you're talking about General>Existing projects into workspace, it says "No projects are found to import". And I'm talking about codes like this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html , you don't import the samples you create them from file>new>others although I do have a problem with them too, e.g. NFCDemo creates with errors since it refers to a Precondition class that doesn't come with the sample

Answer (score 1):

1. Unzip your downloaded sample project to somewhere in your PC.
2. Create a new Android Application project .
3. Replace your newly create android project with your download sample project -> src->main->AndroidManifest.xml file
4. Copy the package folder in src->main->java (eg. com) and paste it in your newly created projects src folder
5. Copy the package folder in src->main->res(eg. com) and paste it in your newly created projects res folder

Give  a refresh in eclipse and Build your project .